# How to add a dynamic span element for only one iteration in an ng-repeat?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

Here's what I'm trying to achieve, I got a table containing a set of inputs:

```
<tr ng-repeat="row in signupForm track by $index" 
    class="data-row">
    <td class="label-cell data-cell">
        <label for="{{row.model}}" ng-bind="(row.label) + ':'"></label>
    </td>
    <td class="data-cell">
        <input type="{{row.type}}" ng-model="user[row.model]"
               placeholder="{{row.placeholder}}" 
               class="round input" id="{{row.model}}">
    </td>
    <td class="error-cell data-cell">
        <span class="error">*</span> //Need to be able to insert image here instead
    </td>
</tr>
```

With the `signupForm` object looking like this:

```
$scope.signupForm = [
    {
        label: 'Firstname',
        type: 'text',
        model: 'firstname',
        placeholder: 'Firstname'
    },
    {
        label: 'Lastname',
        type: 'text',
        model: 'lastname',
        placeholder: 'Lastname'
    },
    {
        label: 'Age',
        type: 'text',
        model: 'age',
        placeholder: 'Age'
    },
    {
        label: 'Country',
        type: 'text',
        model: 'country',
        placeholder: 'Country'
    },
    {
        label: 'Display name',
        type: 'text',
        model: 'displayName',
        placeholder: 'Maximum of 16 characters'
    },
    {
        label: 'E-mail',
        type: 'email',
        model: 'email',
        placeholder: 'Example@backslash.com'
    },
    {
        label: 'Password',
        type: 'password',
        model: 'password',
        placeholder: 'Minimum of 8 characters'
    },
    {
        label: 'Confirm password',
        type: 'password',
        model: 'confirmedPassword',
        placeholder: 'Confirm password'
    }
]
```

Now, for the row that is "displayName" I need to be able to change the span's content in the `error-cell`, but only for this row. I've been sitting here trying to figure out a good way of doing so but I can't come up with a decent way to go about this.

Here's an image to show what I mean, the green represents the row that I need to affect, and the blue is the cell that I need to be able to change.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use an ng-if on that span. The below example just does this for the whole span but you should be able to do something similar

```
<tr ng-repeat="row in signupForm track by $index" 
    class="data-row">
    <td class="label-cell data-cell">
        <label for="{{row.model}}" ng-bind="(row.label) + ':'"></label>
    </td>
    <td class="data-cell">
        <input type="{{row.type}}" ng-model="user[row.model]"
               placeholder="{{row.placeholder}}" 
               class="round input" id="{{row.model}}">
    </td>
    <td class="error-cell data-cell">
        <span class="error" ng-if="row.model === 'displayName'">*</span>
    </td>
</tr>
```

Comment: That works, I edited your answer because you forgot to use ===. :)